# Clicar numa imagem aparecer uma div

Tags: javascript, html

A minha dúvida é a seguinte, ao clicar na imagem 1 aparece a div 1, mas depois ao clicar na imagem 2, desaparece a div 1 e aparece a div 2, e depois ao clicar na imagem 3 desaparece a div 2 e aparece a div.

Como poderei fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Dependendo do que precisar fazer, talvez o que você esteja procurando seja por um Accordion.
Veja exemplo: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer somente com CSS, usando o seletor [**`target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target):

```css
div { display: none }         /* Por padrão, os divs iniciam ocultos. */
div:target { display: block } /* Exibe quando o elemento é alvo. */
```

```html
<a href='#cachorro'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxjHV.jpg'/>
</a>
<a href='#gato'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbkW1.jpg'/>
</a>

<div id='cachorro'>
  <p>lorem cachorro lorem...</p>
</div>
<div id='gato'>
  <p>lorem gato lorem...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso, como aplicaria 5 imagens e 5 divs? Obrigado.

Comment: Criando um `<a>` (contendo a imagem) para cada um dos divs, vinculando o `href` do link com o `id` do div.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer é isso mesmo!

Comment: Agora que tentei aplicar ao meu exemplo, o site ficou todo bugado.

Comment: O que me refiro é que todas as divs ficam bugadas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, caso queira manipular melhor os objetos da página você pode utilizar jquery, fiz um exemplo básico

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #div1 { background-color: yellow }
        #div2 { background-color: blue }
        #div3 { background-color: green }
    </style>
     <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#div1,#div2,#div3').css({'float':'left','margin-top':'300px'}).hide();
            $('#img1,#img2,#img3').css({'cursor':'pointer'});
            $('#img1').click(function(){
                $('#div1').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#div2,#div3').fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('#img2').click(function(){
                $('#div2').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#div1,#div3').fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('#img3').click(function(){
                $('#div3').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#div2,#div1').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
         <img width="50" height="50" id="img1" border="1">
         <img width="50" height="50" id="img2" border="1">
         <img width="50" height="50" id="img3" border="1">

         <div id="div1">div1</div>
         <div id="div2">div2</div>
         <div id="div3">div3</div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

ou somente com css você define o objeto/classe

div#img1:target { ..... }